# How is it possible to blaspheme the Holy Spirit?

Tags: matthew, pneumatology, spirit

Correct me if I am wrong.

The Idea is so easy:

Jesus incarnated on earth, and made some things, behave some behaviours -from the Jews point of view- that made him susceptible to be blasphemed, like:

- Violation of the Sebet.
- Alleged that He is Son of God.
- Association of the Sinners and the Tithers.
- Forgiving the Sins like God.
- Violation of the teachings of the Lord, and trying to supersede the Torah.

The idea is that: how to blaspheme unseen entity, that we don't, we can't react with it.

The Jews blasphemed Jesus because they saw and reacted with him.

The Jews supposed that  behaviours of Jesus are blasphemy, thus, they launched a campaign of anti-blasphemy -from their point of view- against Him. Thus, anti-blasphemy=blasphemy of the unbelievers.

Thus, to be a Target of anti-blasphemy, you should do first what **seems** as blasphemy.

When they (the Jews) said that Jesus gets the Demons out of the obsessed by Satan or by Beelzebule, I don't know if they were blaspheming God the father or not?

Thus, Will the Holy Spirit incarnate on earth, and will be a Target of anti-blasphemy, which is actually a blasphemy of the unbelievers? Or will He be blasphemed in his non physical Spiritual being?

Matthew 12:31-32 (ASV):

> 31. {cf6 Therefore I say unto you, Every sin and blasphemy shall be forgiven unto men; but the blasphemy against the Spirit shall not be forgiven.}
> 32. {cf6 And whosoever shall speak a word against the Son of man, it shall be forgiven him; but whosoever shall speak against the Holy Spirit, it shall not be forgiven him, neither in this world, nor in that which is to come.}

The Bible is clear that the Holy Spirit will be sent to the Believers, or to Humanity after Jesus. But it is not clear if He will incarnate on earth.

Look: - John 14:26, - John 15:26, - John 16:7.

John 14:26 (KJV):

> 26. But the Comforter, {which is} the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

Comment: Before I can properly comment I need to further understand your logic. This is what I have so far...  A being can only be accused of blasphemy if they are capable of committing blasphemy.  If capable of blasphemy, the being must be susceptible to what is considered blasphemy. Only incarnated beings can be considered capable of blasphemy.

Comment: (-1) for shoddy and tortured logic.

Comment: Too many unfounded assumptions here to even understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Havitor the idea is that: how to blaspheme unseen entity, that we don't, we can't react with it. I am just asking, I need you to correct me in an answer if I am wrong.

Comment: @Lucian I need you to correct me if I am wrong, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then there was brought to Him one possessed by a demon, blind and dumb, and He healed him, so that the dumb man spoke and saw. And all the crowds were amazed and said, Is this not the Son of David? But the Pharisees, hearing this, said, This man does not cast out the demons except by Beelzebul, ruler of the demons. But knowing their thoughts, He said to them, Every kingdom divided against itself becomes desolate, and every city or house divided against itself will not stand. And if Satan casts out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then will his kingdom stand?

The crowds of people were enjoying the Lord, they were amazed and appreciative of the healing, and were led by what they saw to...the Doer, the Healer. Isn't this the Son of David? The Christ, the Messiah? Yes! Jesus is the Christ.

The religious leaders, sadly, were jealous. Jealous of another's apparent success. That's also amazing, to me. They couldn't deny that He did this marvelous healing, can you imagine? That the blind and dumb man saw and spoke. How could they be so negative? Cumulatively: how could they be so rejecting? And so, since they couldn't well-deny that Jesus did it, they piously, pompously, religiously attributed Jesus' power to another, invisible, person--Satan. Beelzebul. The anti-God. (Maybe someone else here could get into the origin of that name in Israel.) The ruler of the dung-heap, the lord of the flies (that's a fair 'blasphemy' of Satan, the ruler of the demons).

Apparently to them, Satan, or Beelzebul was a living active person, opposed to the one God, the unique God, the God of Israel, and malevolent to people. And also utilizing people. They should also have know of the Spirit of God, that God is Spirit. He's written of enough in the Scriptures. The Lord Jesus told the Samaritan woman that God is Spirit, and reminded her that she has a human spirit (Jn 4:24) in which, and by which, to render the real worship to the real God. (Namely to contact Him. To drink Him. 4:14). And she, a 'common folk,' also knew to expect the Christ, a man. 4:25.

So there you have the 'Trinity.' Not so much a doctrine, but framed as a matter of course. To experience. God is triune not for doctrine, but for experience. He's just a real living person. Beyond our comprehension, but not beyond our experience. Our experience of salvation. This also demonstrates (again) how the Three persons who are God are never separate. Distinct, yes, but inseparable and never separate. They even, always, work together as One. Jesus **did** cast out the demon by the Spirit of God. Mt 12:28. He said it. The Pharisees recognized that men do supernatural things **by** God, or by another. That's the 'how' they were able to blaspheme the Invisible God or Spirit. By misidentifying who did it, by failing to discern who did it, by being blinded by their own ambition or self.

(You wrote of **targets** of blasphemy (which is good English) so your question should have read: How is it **possible** to blaspheme the Holy Spirit? Or: How is someone non-physical and invisible blasphemeable (if we can make that a word)? You wouldn't use the word 'susceptible' here since that refers to the target's own subjective experience: the harm or feeling he receives from the speech.

You also wouldn't use or need to use the word 'incarnation' here because that is a 'term of art' referring to the Son, the Second of the Trinity, putting on flesh; and that complicates it, confusing the readers. You make your point by saying simply 'physical' or 'material.' Lastly, even when you do use 'incarnation,' you needn't use 'earthly' because that is included in the meaning of Incarnation, 1 Cor 15:45-49)